# string splitting after every other comma in string in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have string which contains every word separated by comma. I want to split the string by every other comma in python. How should I do this?

eg, `"xyz,abc,jkl,pqr"` should give `"xyzabc"` as one string and `"jklpqr"` as another string

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you split by every comma the result would be xyz abc jul pqr as four different strings.

Comment: ok example please answer according to example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably easier to split on every comma, and then rejoin pairs

```
>>> original = 'a,1,b,2,c,3'
>>> s = original.split(',')
>>> s
['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3']
>>> alternate = map(''.join, zip(s[::2], s[1::2]))
>>> alternate
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: One mild warning: this has the possibly unintended consequence that if original doesn't have an even number of elements the last entry is silently lost.  Maybe that's okay, although I prefer to force myself to be explicit when I want that.

Comment: True - I'm not sure what the cleanest way to handle it here is. Maybe just wrap it in a function and check explicitly.

Comment: @Useless: You could use `izip_longest` (see my answer).

Comment: Apparently I can't test that in the office, but if I have a chance to verify an `izip_longest` version at home, I'll edit it in.  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 2):

Split, and rejoin.

So, to split:

```
In [173]: "a,b,c,d".split(',')
Out[173]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

And to rejoin:

```
In [193]: z = iter("a,b,c,d".split(','))
In [194]: [a+b for a,b in zip(*([z]*2))]
Out[194]: ['ab', 'cd']
```

This works because `([z]*2)` is a list of two elements, both of which are the same iterator `z`. Thus, zip takes the first, then second element from `z` to create each tuple.

This also works as a oneliner, because in `[foo]*n` `foo` is evaluated only once, whether or not it is a variable or a more complex expression:

```
In [195]: [a+b for a,b in zip(*[iter("a,b,c,d".split(','))]*2)]
Out[195]: ['ab', 'cd']
```

I've also cut out a pair of brackets, because unary `*` has lower precedence than binary `*`.

Thanks to @pillmuncher for pointing out that this can be extended with `izip_longest` to handle lists with an odd number of elements:

```
In [214]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [215]: [a+b for a,b in izip_longest(*[iter("a,b,c,d,e".split(','))]*2, fillvalue='')]
Out[215]: ['ab', 'cd', 'e']
```

(See: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest )

Comment: @pillmuncher Well, `zip(z,z)` can't be a oneliner, and this demonstrates the zip-with-list-multiply idiom. Good point on `itertools.izip_longest()`, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "a,b,c,d".split(",")
print ["".join(str[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(str), 2)]
```

Comment: (a) don't use str as a variable (b) Use of indices in list comprehensions can be rather cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

Just split on every comma, then combine it back:

```
splitList = someString.split(",")
joinedString = ','.join([splitList[i - 1] + splitList[i] for i in range(1, len(splitList), 2)]
```

Answer (score -3):

Like this

```
"a,b,c,d".split(',')
```

Comment: do u mean `"a,b,c,d".split(',')`?But it'll give me a b c d which i don't want