# Calculate an Erdos Number from a list of paper authors

Tags: python, python-2.7

The Erdős number describes the "collaborative distance" between a person and mathematician Paul Erdős, as measured by authorship of mathematical papers. To be assigned an Erdős number, someone must be a coauthor of a research paper with another person who has a finite Erdős number. Paul Erdős has an Erdős number of zero. Anybody else's Erdős number is k + 1 where k is the lowest Erdős number of any coauthor. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_number).

Given a list of authors (and papers), I would like to produce an Erdős number for each of a set of authors. The source data is as follows(from an input .txt file):

```
1(means only one scenario from this input, could have more than one from other entries)

4 3
Smith, M.N., Martin, G., Erdos, P.: Newtonian forms of prime factors
Erdos, P., Reisig, W.: Stuttering in petri nets
Smith, M.N., Chen, X.: First order derivates in structured programming
Jablonski, T., Hsueh, Z.: Selfstabilizing data structures
Smith, M.N.
Hsueh, Z.
Chen, X.
```

The authors to calculate Erdős numbers for are:

```
Smith, M.N.
Hsueh, Z.
Chen, X.
```

My current plan is to take the names out of each entry and form a list (or a list of lists) of the names. But I am unsure of the best way to do this. What should I use? numpy? readline?

Update:
the output should  look like this:

```
Scenario 1
Smith, M.N. 1
Hsueh, Z. infinity
Chen, X. 2
```

Comment: Can you use the quote and/or code features so we can see how the sample input is formatted? And describe what you want the output (the "check list"?) to look like by giving us the desired result for your sample input?

Comment: Meanwhile, you probably don't want to use `readline` here. A `for line in file:` loop is usually easier than `while True:` `line = file.readline()` `if not line: break` loop. But manually reading the file and parsing each record (with string methods or with regexps), yes, that's probably what you want.

Comment: It appears you have two problems: a) extracting the data (names, authors) from the text input, b) calculating the Erdos number. What is your expected output?

Comment: I added some details in the question.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand the problem, note that basically this is just [unweighted single-source shortest path problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579399/shortest-path-fewest-nodes-for-unweighted-graph), which can be solved using [Breadth-first Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).
The graph in your problem is defined as:

1. Each node represents an author.
2. There is an edge between two nodes iff there is a paper in which the two authors represented by the two nodes co-authored it together.

For your example, the graph is as follows:

```
Reisig
  |
  |
 Erdos -- Martin
  |      /
  |     /
  |    /
  |   /
  |  /
 Smith -- Chen


Jablonski -- Hsueh
```

So the algorithm will initially assign distance 0 to Erdos and infinity to others. Then as it iteratively visits the neighbors, it assigns increasing distance. So next iteration will assign distance (or in this case Erdos number) of 1 to Reisig, Martin, and Smith. The next and final iteration will assign distance of 2 to Chen. The distance for Jablonski and Hsueh will be left as infinity.

The graph representation using [Adjacency List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list):

```
e = Erdos
r = Reisig
m = Martin
s = Smith
c = Chen
j = Jablonski
h = Hsueh

e: r m s
r: e
m: e s
s: e c
c: s
j: h
h: j
```

with the code to solve it in Python:

```
import Queue

def calc_erdos(adj_lst):
    erdos_numbers = {}
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    queue.put(('Erdos, P.', 0))
    while not queue.empty():
        (cur_author, dist) = queue.get()
        if cur_author not in erdos_numbers:
            erdos_numbers[cur_author] = dist
        for author in adj_lst[cur_author]:
            if author not in erdos_numbers:
                queue.put((author, dist+1))
    return erdos_numbers

def main():
    num_scenario = int(raw_input())
    raw_input() # Read blank line
    for idx_scenario in range(1, num_scenario+1):
        [num_papers, num_queries] = [int(num) for num in raw_input().split()]
        adj_lst = {}
        for _ in range(num_papers):
            paper = raw_input()
            [authors, title] = paper.split(':')
            authors = [author.strip() for author in authors.split(',')]
            authors = [', '.join(first_last) for first_last in zip(authors[::2], authors[1::2])]
            # Build the adjacency list
            for author in authors:
                author_neighbors = adj_lst.get(author,set())
                for coauthor in authors:
                    if coauthor == author:
                        continue
                    author_neighbors.add(coauthor)
                adj_lst[author] = author_neighbors

        erdos_numbers = calc_erdos(adj_lst)

        print 'Scenario %d' % idx_scenario
        for _ in range(num_queries):
            author = raw_input()
            print '%s %s' % (author, erdos_numbers.get(author,'infinity'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

which with the input:

```
1

4 3
Smith, M.N., Martin, G., Erdos, P.: Newtonian forms of prime factors
Erdos, P., Reisig, W.: Stuttering in petri nets
Smith, M.N., Chen, X.: First order derivates in structured programming
Jablonski, T., Hsueh, Z.: Selfstabilizing data structures
Smith, M.N.
Hsueh, Z.
Chen, X.
```

will output:

```
Scenario 1
Smith, M.N. 1
Hsueh, Z. infinity
Chen, X. 2
```

*Note*:

The more general problem can be described as [single-source shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Single-source_shortest_paths), for which the simplest solution is using [Djikstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted an edit to your question to try and clarify what you are hoping to achieve. Based on this I've written the following code to answer what I *thought* you were trying to ask:

```
f = ['Smith, M.N., Martin, G., Erdos, P.: Newtonian forms of prime factors',
'Erdos, P., Reisig, W.: Stuttering in petri nets',
'Smith, M.N., Chen, X.: First order derivates in structured programming',
'Jablonski, T., Hsueh, Z.: Selfstabilizing data structures']

author_en = {} # Dict to hold scores/author
coauthors = []
targets = ['Smith, M.N.','Hsueh, Z.','Chen, X.']

for line in f:
    # Split the line on the :
    authortext,papers = line.split(':')

    # Split on comma, then rejoin author (every 2)
    # See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366650/string-splitting-after-every-other-comma-in-string-in-python
    authors = authortext.split(', ')
    authors = map(', '.join, zip(authors[::2], authors[1::2]))

    # Authors now contains a list of authors names    
    coauthors.append( authors )

    for author in authors:
        author_en[ author ] = None

author_en['Erdos, P.'] = 0 # Special case
```

At this point we now we have a list of lists: each list containing co-authors from a given publication and a dict to hold the scores. We need to iterate over each paper and allocate a score to the authors. I'm not entirely clear on the calculation of the Erdos score, but you probably want to loop the score allocation until there is no change - to account for later papers affecting earlier scores.

```
for ca in coauthors:
    minima = None
    for a in ca:
        if author_en[a] != None and ( author_en[a]<minima or minima is None ): # We have a score
            minima = author_en[a]

    if minima != None:
        for a in ca:
            if author_en[a] == None:
                author_en[a] = minima+1 # Lowest score of co-authors + 1

for author in targets:
    print "%s: %s" % ( author, author_en[author] )
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves this case, but not for a different input. I am still looking at  your code and trying to learn.

Comment: It is probably failing due for the lack of a loop around the final part to re-calculate changes that depend on papers further down the list. However, @justhalf has posted a better answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for Java implementation:

```
import java.util.*;

public class P10044 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cases = c.nextInt();

    for (int currentCase = 1; currentCase<=cases; currentCase++) {

        int p = c.nextInt();
        int n = c.nextInt();

        c.nextLine();

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> graph = new HashMap<>();
        String[] testingNames = new String[n];
        ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();

        HashMap<String, Integer> eNums = new HashMap<>();

        while (p-- > 0) {

            String[] paperAuthors = c.nextLine().split(":")[0].split("\\.,");
            for (int i = 0; i < paperAuthors.length; i++) {
                if (paperAuthors[i].charAt(paperAuthors[i].length() - 1) != '.')
                    paperAuthors[i] += '.';
                paperAuthors[i] = paperAuthors[i].trim();
            }

            for (String author : paperAuthors)
                if (!authors.contains(author))
                    authors.add(author);

            // create and update the graph
            for (String name : paperAuthors) {

                ArrayList<String> updatedValue;

                if (graph.keySet().contains(name))
                    updatedValue = graph.get(name);
                else
                    updatedValue = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String paperAuthor : paperAuthors)
                    if (!paperAuthor.equals(name))
                        updatedValue.add(paperAuthor);

                graph.put(name, updatedValue);

            }
        }


        //initialize the eNums map:
        for (String author : authors)
            if (!author.equals("Erdos, P."))
                eNums.put(author, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            else
                eNums.put(author, 0);


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            testingNames[i] = c.nextLine();

        calculateEnums("Erdos, P.", graph, eNums);


        System.out.println("Scenario " + currentCase);
        for (String name : testingNames)
            if (!eNums.keySet().contains(name) || eNums.get(name) == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                System.out.println(name + " infinity");
            else
                System.out.println(name + " " + eNums.get(name));

    }

}

private static void calculateEnums(String name, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> graph,
                                   HashMap<String, Integer> eNums) {

    ArrayList<String> notCalculated = new ArrayList<>();
    notCalculated.add(name);

    while (notCalculated.size() > 0) {
        String currentName = notCalculated.get(0);
        for (String connectedName : graph.get(currentName)) {
            if (eNums.get(connectedName) > eNums.get(currentName)) {
                eNums.put(connectedName, eNums.get(currentName) + 1);
                if(!notCalculated.contains(connectedName))
                    notCalculated.add(connectedName);
            }
        }
        notCalculated.remove(0);
    }

//        recursive implementation but will result in TLE

//        for(String connected: graph.get(name)) {
//            if (eNums.get(connected) > eNums.get(name)) {
//                eNums.put(connected, eNums.get(name) + 1);
//                calculateEnums(connected, graph, eNums);
//            }
//        }
}
}
```