# Python - Splitting a string of names separated by spaces and commas

Tags: python, django

I have an API feeding into my program into a django many to many model field. The names of the individuals within my database are structured with a separated first name and last name. However, the API is sending a bulk list of names structured as as a string list as so: `"Jones, Bob Smith, Jason Donald, Mic"` (Last name-comma-space-first name-space-new last name- etc.)

How would I separate this string in a way that would allow me to filter and add a particular user to the many-to-many field?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string splitting after every other comma in string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366650/string-splitting-after-every-other-comma-in-string-in-python)

Comment: What if first or last name contains a space?

Comment: @fferri indeed, it may be an API broken by design. https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/ My introduction to this  (in larval stage) was the name O'Connor back in VMS DCL days, coming out as plain "O".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer excludes the case where a first name or last name contains space (this case is much more complicated as you will have a word with a space on his left AND on his right).

You need to replace the -comma-space- by something without a space (because you also have a space between two different names).

```py
string = "Jones, Bob Smith, Jason Donald, Mic"

names = []
for name in string.replace(', ', ',').split(' '): 
    name = name.split(',')
    last_name = name[0]
    first_name = name[1]
    names.append((last_name, first_name))
names
```

Output:
`[('Jones', 'Bob'), ('Smith', 'Jason'), ('Donald', 'Mic')]`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Based on the previous data imports it looks like all names that would normally have a space in either the first or last name have been condensed to eliminate the space. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
s = "Jones, Bob Smith, Jason Donald, Mic"

list(re.findall(r'(\S+), (\S+)', s))
# [('Jones', 'Bob'), ('Smith', 'Jason'), ('Donald', 'Mic')]
```

Comment: Great solution- may also try implementing that.